# Restarting the http server by closing it completely

Tags: python

how can i achieve this ?
if i run the python http server script in cmd environment (i-e; running it via double clicking on the server.py file and not from opening the script in edit mode and then clicking run or pressing f5)

once the server has  received the http post data from a remote client, and defined actions have been completed now the script automatically closes the HTTP server "cmd window" and restarts it?

Comment: the server is working fine and performing all the defined tasks 
what i dont know is how to make it close the cmd window and restart it ?

Comment: Can you show us some code so that we can see what your are doing? And how do you start it? Should we presume that you are running it in Windows? A [mre] would be ideal.